# How to deal with multiple select elements on one form and livewire page

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Can you help me with how to deal with multiple select elements on one form and livewire page? I tried but when I change one and in a method like 'updatedDate' which is called after date changed the other two parameters 'city_from_id' and 'city_to_id' and others are null. How to deal with it? I need to make a form that will check available routes depending on two city params and one date parameter. And if all Ok then the user can fill up the rest of the form. But I can't find a way how to make it.

[gist is here](https://gist.github.com/stojankukrika/de0d19d5f19b8006f0a41d9e5d8df463)

and at the test method I get results(when change select for city_from_id):
[image]

when change select for date:
[image]

when change select for city_to_id:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need real-time validation you can do it like so

add this to your form element

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="the name of the function you want">
```

and add button type submit if you did not add it for the form.

If you need real-time validation

you need -with the modifications above - to remove the defer modifier from every input,
and add this to your component class

```
 public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}
```

Comment: It's OK but when I changed 'date' I only get date value, when change city_from_id, only get city_from_id and lose date value :( I do didn't find a way to get all values at once.

Comment: And if I used Deferred Updating I only get changed values after the last form submitted, not the prev.selected values :(

Answer (score 0):

if you use 'defer', you only can get the bind values on the next request, in your case you need some submission action to the backend and handle the data.
Otherwise, without the 'defer', you can do something like this:

```
public $count = 0;

// simplify this 
public function updatedSearch($value)
{
   $this->test();
}

public function test()
{
   // UPDATED
   if ($this->search['date'] != null && $this->search['city_from_id']  != null && $this->search['city_to_id'] != null) {
      $this->count ++ ;

   } else {
      if($this->count > 0) {
          $this->count -- ;
      }
   }
}
```

I mean, this way you can manage your events live and take action.

And this is my solution working:
[image]

Comment: I tried that but always get 'do another thing' in the test() method, that is the reason why I asked this question. When I changed 'date' I only get date value, when change city_from_id, only get city_from_id and lose date value :( I do didn't find a way to get all values at once.

Comment: And if I used Deferred Updating I only get changed values after the last form submitted, not the prev.selected values :(

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe I do not do something right :( but I always get one value, as you can see oat pictures :(

Comment: hey that's normal, I haven't clear the answer to that behavior but no matter in it. If you can, for test, add a submit button and on click after select all data, make dd to $search property and you will see all the selected values filled in the array

Comment: I tried that. Yes, it's OK after first filling up but after changing something it has only that value if I add defer.

Comment: you can take a look at my gist here https://gist.github.com/stojankukrika/de0d19d5f19b8006f0a41d9e5d8df463

Comment: just, don't test it with the dump, instead, try any action with a property you can reflect it in frontend the result

Comment: looks like in that way that works :) I do not understand why but it works, without dd or dump it works :(